# How to execute a function in Qt when a variable changes its value in the QML?

Tags: c++, qt, signals, signals-slots

```
error: no matching function for call to 'SimulationMode::connect(QString&, const char*, SimulationMode* const, const char*)'
QObject::connect (m_standingAgvID, SIGNAL (f(int)), this, SLOT (d(int)));
```

Here, `m_standingAgvID` is an object of a `QString` variable which is also used in the `Q_PROPERTY`.

f(int) and d(int) have been defined and declared in the respective signal and slot areas of the cpp code.

Considering:

> QString does not emit signals. Perhaps you should tell us what you are
>   trying to achieve. –  cmannett85

and

> QString itself is not an QObject, it cannot connect signals and slots.
>   –  Tay2510

I have a simple variable of let us say `int` type which is a class member and I have made it a `Q_PROPERTY`.

This variable will be set in `QML`. When its value changes, I'd like to call a signal in `Qt`.

That's all.

Comment: `QString` does not emit signals.  Perhaps you should tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Where have you declared `f(int)`? Because `QString` sure does not have such member (and no signal/slots).

Comment: `QString` itself is not an [`QObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#details), it cannot  connect signals and slots.

Comment: @JBL "f(int) and d(int) have been defined and declared in the respective signal and slot areas of the cpp code."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using your example regarding `int`s, it would be done like this:

```
class foo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY( int value READ getValue WRITE setValue NOTIFY valueChanged )
public:
    explicit foo( QObject* parent = nullptr ) :
        QObject{ parent }, i_{ 0 } {}
    virtual ~foo() {}

    int getValue() const { return i_; }
public slots:
    void setValue( int value )
    {
        if ( value != i_ ) {
            i_ = value;
            emit valueChanged( i_ );
        }
    }
signals:
    void valueChanged( int value );
private:
    int i_;
};
```

In short you have to manually emit change notification signals regarding members.

Comment: so, where am I supposed to write the code in c++ which is supposed to get executed when that variable changes value?

Comment: Well if your executed code is inside `foo` then you can put it inside `setValue(int value)`, otherwise just connect to the `valueChanged` signal as you would with any other class.

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius Did you read the document about [**Signals & Slots?**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html). The examples can help you clarify the idea.